# Помогите подключить файлы из папки другого сайта PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

Добрый день, что-то не могу понять как подключить файлы с другого каталога сайта.
Например у меня на хосте висят две папки с разными сайтами `site1.com` и `site2.com` и мне надо вытащить например с `site1.com/img/img1.jpg` картинку и вставить её в site2.com. Или прийдется лепить через `http://site1.com/img/img1.jpg` ???  Кто в теме подскажите плс.

Comment: Скопируйте ее, если такой url на странице не устраивает.

Comment: Копировать много, такой юрл устраивает меня, единственное влияние на скорость

Comment: симлинк на директорию изображений сделайте

Comment: Не секу, можно пример?  я чтото в гугле ничего не нашел разъяснительного

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ваше дерево каталогов имеет следующий вид:

```
C:\www\    (/var/www)
  -- site1.ru\
  ---- img\
  ------- img1.jpg
  -- site2.ru
```

и вы хотите на сайте `site2.ru` подключить изображения из `www\site1.ru\img`, не копируя непосредственно файлы, то можете воспользоваться несколькими способами:

1. самое очевидное, использовать полный путь с указанием домена `<img src="http://site1.ru/img/img1"/>`
2. создать символическую ссылку на каталог изображений.

Для этого в windows системах:

```
cd C:\www\site2.ru
mklink /D img "..\site1.ru\img"
```

для linux систем

```
cd /var/www/site2.ru
ln -s "../site1.ru/img" img
```

после чего на `site2` можете использовать `<img src="/img/img1.jpg">`.

Возможно,потребуется настройка вэб-сервера, чтобы он разрашал переход по символическим ссылкам. У apache что-то было про `FollowSymlinks`, у `IIS` хз